# Adding line breaks to output file via fwrite

Tags: php, fwrite

I'm trying to format the file I'm creating below so that each name/value pair is on its own line

I'm sure this is easy, but my .ini file is not formatting the line breaks at all. what am I missing?

```
function wpseTest()
{
    $query = "SELECT option_name, option_value FROM wp_options where option_name like 'test|_%' escape '|' AND option_value > ''";
    global $wpdb;
    $matches = $wpdb->get_results($query);

    $mySettings = '[settings]\r\n';

    foreach ($matches as $result){
        $mySettings .= $result->option_name;
        $mySettings .= ' = ';
        $mySettings .= $result->option_value;
        $mySettings .= '\r\n';
    }

    $mySettingsFileLocation = WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/test/settings-backup.ini';
    $mySettingsFile = fopen($mySettingsFileLocation, 'w');
    fwrite($mySettingsFile, $mySettings);
    fclose($mySettingsFile);
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Special characters like `\r` and `\n` do not get interpreted in single quotes. Use double quotes instead.

```
$mySettings = "[settings]\r\n";
```

And

```
$mySettings .= "\r\n";
```

Comment: This only came out as extra space, like a tab. But adding "<br>" did the trick for me

Answer (score 5):

You can use the platform dependent constant `PHP_EOL` instead

```
$mySettings = '[settings]' . PHP_EOL;
// ..
$mySettings .= PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Outputs: This will not expand: \n a newline
echo 'This will not expand: \n a newline';
```

[put it in double quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

```
function wpseTest()
{
    $query = "SELECT option_name, option_value FROM wp_options where option_name like 'test|_%' escape '|' AND option_value > ''";
    global $wpdb;
    $matches = $wpdb->get_results($query);

    $mySettings = "[settings]\r\n";

    foreach ($matches as $result){
        $mySettings .= $result->option_name;
        $mySettings .= ' = ';
        $mySettings .= $result->option_value;
        $mySettings .= "\r\n";
    }

    $mySettingsFileLocation = WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/test/settings-backup.ini';
    $mySettingsFile = fopen($mySettingsFileLocation, 'w');
    fwrite($mySettingsFile, $mySettings);
    fclose($mySettingsFile);
}
```